# Argument constructor call invocation

Tags: c++, constructor

I am a bit puzzled about this. When default stack allocated object construction is allowed as member varaiable of other struct, why not parameterized construction ? Does [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) has anything to do with this ? I tried on C++0X as well at ideone and got the same result.

```
struct foo{
    foo() {}
    foo(int i) {}
};

struct bar{
  foo obj;      // Allowed
  foo obj2(10); // Not Allowed
};
```

> Error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant

[IdeOne Demo](http://ideone.com/99BXPq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your link to Most Vexing Parse discusses instantiation of non-member variables (variables which are not a member of a class/struct).   The example you've shown is that of member variables being declared in a struct; for which you would typically initialise them in a constructor

```
struct bar
{
    foo obj;
    foo obj2;
    bar() : obj2(10) {}
};
```

The Most Vexing Parse problem occurs in situations such as the below:

```
struct baz
{
    baz(int n) {}
};

void foo()
{
    baz meow(int());
}
```

where the identifier `meow` appears to be a function declaration of type `baz (int)`, due to the 'most vexing parse' issues described in your link.  (the **int()** which at first glance appears to be default-initialisation actually turns out to be simply the data type `int`)

Answer (score 1):

write

```
struct bar {
  foo obj;
  foo obj2;
  foo(): obj2(10) {}
}
```

This way, when instantiating `bar`, `obj2` construction will be made with 10.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to C++11, you couldn't initialize members in the declaration unless they were `static const` and integral.

In C++11, you can use uniform initialization and in-class member initializtion:

```
foo obj2{10};
```

Since the constructor is not explicit, you can also do this:

```
foo obj2 = 10;
```

Not in C++11, you have to use a member initializer in the constructor list.